# Where is dictionary size changing?

Tags: python, exception

In my [Python Utilities Github repo](https://github.com/dotancohen/pytility/) I have a function which removes strips nonprinting characters and invalid Unicode bytes from strings, mappings, and sequences:

```
def filterCharacters(s):
    """
    Strip non printable characters

    @type s dict|list|tuple|bytes|string
    @param s Object to remove non-printable characters from

    @rtype dict|list|tuple|bytes|string
    @return An object that corresponds with the original object, nonprintable characters removed.
    """

    validCategories = (
        'Lu', 'Ll', 'Lt', 'LC', 'Lm', 'Lo', 'L', 'Mn', 'Mc', 'Me', 'M', 'Nd', 'Nl', 'No', 'N', 'Pc',
        'Pd', 'Ps', 'Pe', 'Pi', 'Pf', 'Po', 'P', 'Sm', 'Sc', 'Sk', 'So', 'S', 'Zs', 'Zl', 'Zp', 'Z'
    )
    convertToBytes = False

    if isinstance(s, dict):
        new = {}
        for k,v in s.items(): # This is the offending line
            new[k] = filterCharacters(v)
        return new

    if isinstance(s, list):
        new = []
        for item in s:
            new.append(filterCharacters(item))
        return new

    if isinstance(s, tuple):
        new = []
        for item in s:
            new.append(filterCharacters(item))
        return tuple(new)

    if isinstance(s, bytes):
        s = s.decode('utf-8')
        convertToBytes = True

    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = ''.join(c for c in s if unicodedata.category(c) in validCategories)
        if convertToBytes:
            s = s.encode('utf-8')
        return s

    else:
        return None
```

Sometimes this function throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./util.py", line 56, in filterCharacters
    for k,v in s.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I don't see where I am changing the dictionary sent as an argument. Why is this exception being thrown, then?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of input is causing the error?

Comment: Are you using multithreading?

Comment: It smells like it is somehow related to it being a recursive call.

Comment: Thanks. I do agree that the issue is the recursion. But I'm not sure where actual input values are being changed.

Comment: @user2357112: Actually, there are multiple threads which are calling this function, but each is using its own `s` object. I am _not_ sharing that object across multiple threads (Danger! Danger!).

Comment: The recursion is not causing this problem. At no point is the code adding or removing keys to the dictionary. But if you were to use multithreading, and another thread were to add or remove keys, you'd see exactly this error.

Comment: Maybe you're sharing `s`'s insides. The only other way I could see this failing this way is if you had a crazy subclass of a built-in type that overloaded one of these operations to modify something. Even `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` don't do that.

Comment: Thanks Martin and 2357112. I'm checking now to ensure that none of the threads are sharing objects. Is it certain that twil's assertion that modifying `s` is wrong? The issue is intermittent, and it is taking me some time to trigger it, so I cannot be certain if that is the case or not. Thanks.

Comment: It's defenetly wrong:/ Could you provide example data which is causing error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3 `dict.items()` returns `dict_view` object (not `list` as in python 2). Looking through CPython code I've noticed comments like

`Objects/dictobject.c`

```
dict_items(register PyDictObject *mp) 
{
    ...
    /* Preallocate the list of tuples, to avoid allocations during
     * the loop over the items, which could trigger GC, which
     * could resize the dict. :-(
     */
    ...

    if (n != mp->ma_used) {
        /* Durnit.  The allocations caused the dict to resize.
         * Just start over, this shouldn't normally happen.
         */
        Py_DECREF(v);
        goto again;
    }
    ...
}
```

So not only dict deletions and insertions could cause this error to show but any allocations! oO!

Procedure of resizing is also interesting. Look at

```
static int
dictresize(PyDictObject *mp, Py_ssize_t minused)
{
    ...
}
```

But that's all internals.

### Solution

Try converting `dict_view` to `list` with

```
if isinstance(s, dict):
    new = {}
    items = [i for i in s.items()]
    for k,v in items:
        new[k] = filterCharacters(v)
    return new
```

Comment: Thanks, twil. Might this be a bug in Python that I'm running into this situation, then, as it "shouldn't normally happen" as per the dev's comments? Should I file it?

Comment: Why not? Try to file it. But documented bug (especially in one of the base types) is a feature;) though not pleasant one